# Integral involving Marcum Q-function, modified Bessel function, exp and power

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

We know that the first order Marcum Q-function can be represented as
$$Q_1(a, b)=\int_{b}^{\infty} t \exp{(-(t^2+a^2)/2)} I_0(a t) \, dt ,$$
I am trying to compute the following integral $A$ and $B$:
$$A=\int_0^{\infty} xg(x) dx$$,
$$B=\int_0^{\infty} x^2g(x) dx$$
where 
$$g(x)=G'(x) $$ and
$$G(x)= Q_1(\frac{v_1}{\sigma_1},\frac{x}{\sigma_1})Q_1(\frac{v_2}{\sigma_2},\frac{x}{\sigma_2}) $$

Thank you for your time and kindness.

With respect.